# Bit defines textbox visibility

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't know how to fix or handle this issue. But I currenlty have 2 links as following:
`NavigateUrl="~/Admin/ManageProducts.aspx?IsMeal=true` and False.

When it is set to TRUE I want txtDescription to be visible, and when set to FALSE I wan't txtDescription to be invisible.

IsMeal is a BIT in my database. So I need to define somehow that, when `ManageProducts.aspx?IsMeal=true` then txtDescription should be visible, and reverse

```
FALSE = invisible
```

But how do I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ManageProducts.aspx.cs file place this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Request.QueryString["IsMeal"] != null) {
        if (Boolean.Parse(Request.QueryString["IsMeal"])) {
            txtDescription.Visible = true;
        }
        else {
            txtDescription.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah this sample did exactly what I was looking for! Cheers mate

Comment: You used an IF statement? Seriously?

Answer (score 3):

In your `Page_Load()` method you can add the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   txtDescription.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString("IsMeal"));
}
```

Comment: that won't work because you are using comparison `==` instead of assignment `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just set the property accordingly:

```
bool isMeal = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString["IsMeal"]);
txtDescription.Visible = isMeal;
```